# vagrant up しようとすると remote catalog にアクセス出来ないと言われる

Tags: macos, vagrant

MacをSierra にアップデートでして、vagrantを1.8.7にあげてから新しいboxをインストールしようとすると以下のようなエラーになりました。

```
The box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog.
```

Answer (score 1):

この問題の原因は vagrant 1.8.7 のIssueでバンドルされる `curl`のバージョンがOSXと競合してるせいだそうです。

```
sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl
```

で同封されている`curl`を削除しましょう。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog